# Android - callback for MediaRecorder started recording

Tags: android, callback, android-progressbar, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

My app needs to record video with a maximum time of 8 seconds. This is already implemented with MediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(long milliseconds).
The app also needs a progress bar in the top and a label with a count down of the remaining time.

The problem here is that there's an offset between the UI and the MediaRecorder progress, and this leads to confusion in the user. For example, the user thinks that he/she recorded something because the progress in the UI said so, but the media recorder cut off the video a second earlier.

The challenge is to start the progress bar and counter at the exact same time as the recorder actually starts recording. 
I've tried starting the timer after MediaRecorder.start(), in a callback when the created file is modified for the first time, but I haven't found a way to achieve this in a correct way. We tried setting a hard coded offset to these values but of course it didn't work the same for every device.

I wish there was a callback from the MediaRecorder to inform that it has actually started to record the video, or maybe the current length.

Is the problem clear? Has someone solved this before?

Answer (score 0):

MediaRecorder has known issues with cutting off audio early. I implemented a recorder with a button - clicking the button to stop the recorder would actually yield an audio file with the last second cut off. 
Not sure if your UI offset is a separate issue, but I would try extending the MediaRecorder by half a second after the user attempts to end it. You can either do this by changing the maximum time to 8.5 seconds, or just using this line of code:

```
   android.os.SystemClock.sleep(500);
```